# Python, сгладить углы графика, построенного с помощью matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Помогите привести график к более интерполируемому виду, если так можно выразиться, то есть у меня есть 5 точек на графике, которые соединены отрезкам, а мне бы эти отрезки сгладить.
Проблема в том, что функция "for_drawing", по которой я и рисую, принимает только целые значения, следовательно промежуточные значения посчитать не получится, но сгладить то надо, подскажите, как это реализовать, заранее спасибо!

Что я пробовал делать:

- `plt.setp(lines, color='red', linewidth=2.0, antialiased=True)`#antialiased по идее должен сглаживать, а по факту совершенно не изменил картинку
- `x = np.linspace(0, 5, num=11, endpoint=True)`#linspace должна найти промежуточные значения, но как она найдет, если моя функция не принимает значения float, таким образом выводит ошибку

[Мой код](https://pastebin.com/Hu9m4XCV)

[image: График, который у меня получился и который нужно сгладить]

Comment: что у вас за функция такая? код приведите хотя бы.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8ir7gMU9

Comment: antialiased гладит пиксели на поворотах

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, вы упираетесь в `range` В вашей функции с целыми числами? тогда попробуйте вместо нее `np.arange(0.0, n+1.0, 0.1)`, например.

Comment: Это, кстати, как вариант, попробую

Answer (score 1):

Подключите https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html она дорисует больше точек чтоб график стал глаже. Смотрите примеры, сгладить график можно по-разному

Comment: Я пробовал, по описанию действительно то что мне нужно. Это второй пункт того, что я пробовал, но, как я говорил, мне выдало ошибку.

Comment: какую ошибку вам выдало?